# Клиент-сервер на TCP сокетах SFML не передает и не получает пакеты

Tags: c++, сокет, tcp, sfml

Не могу понять почему в пакет не передается по соединению, хотя к localhost и сервер и клиент подключаются.
Код сервера:

```
sf::Socket::Status Server::send(sf::Packet& packet) {
    return (socket.send(packet));
}

bool Server::start() {
    return (socket.connect(ip, port) == sf::Socket::Done);
}
```

Код клиента:

```
sf::Socket::Status Client::receive(sf::Packet& packet) {
    return (socket.receive(packet));
}

bool Client::start() {
    return (socket.connect(ip, port) == sf::Socket::Done);
}
```

Код отправки пакета:

```
packet << i;
server.send(packet);
packet.clear();
```

Код получение пакета:

```
packet >> j;
packet.clear();
```

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, [минимальный и самодостаточный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), чтобы можно было воспроизвести вашу проблему. Примеры из документации `SFML` у вас работают?

Comment: @Tocic Я уже осознал свою самую большую ошибку, то что у меня сервер не должен коннектится, он должен слушать и подключать сокет к каждому клиенту, но он у меня просто теперь не запускается, но это уже другой вопрос